# Entity Framework 4.3.1 Code First relation not working when getting data

Tags: database, ef-code-first, relation, entity-framework-4.3

This is the first time I am making a project in C# with the Entity Framework 4.3.1. I am having troubles with getting all the data from the Tournament table, the Address to be precise.

First of all, here is my Code First code. When I run this, the 2 tables are created correctly with the correct relation. I have a lot more columns defined in those classes, but for this example I only show a few.

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public EFDbContext()
        : base("ApplicationServices")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Tournament> tournaments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> addresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

    public class Tournament
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int TournamentId { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage="Tournament name is a required field")]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage="Address is a required field")]
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {   
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int AddressId { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage="Street name is a required field")]
        public string Street { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage="House number is a required field")]
        public string HouseNo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I insert a new Tournament with an Address and I go check in the database if the relation is used I can see it worked. The tournament has an Address_AddressId value pointing to the new inserted Address. But when I try to get the info by doing this:

```
Tournament tournament = context.tournaments.Find(id);
```

and I debug it, I can see all the data from Tournament is in the tournament object, except for the Address. This is set to null and I have absolutely no idea why.

Can you guys help me out?

Thanks in advance,
Bart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get familiar a bit how you can load related data with Entity Framework. An introduction is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx These are really basics you need to know to work efficiently with Entity Framework.

The behaviour you are seeing is expected. Entity Framework doesn't load a navigation property - like `Tournament.Address` - automatically when you just load the parent entity `Tournament` (with `Find` in your example).

There are basically three options to load related data:

- Eager loading:

  ```cs
  Tournament tournament = context.tournaments
      .Include(t => t.Address) // <- "eager loading"
      .SingleOrDefault(t => t.TournamentId == id);
  ```

  Tournament and address will we loaded in a single roundtrip and database query.
- Lazy loading: Mark your navigation property as `virtual`:

  ```cs
  public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
  ```

  EF will dynamically create a proxy object (derived from `Tournament`) when you load the tournament which is capable to load the related entity as soon as you access one of its properties:

  ```cs
  Tournament tournament = context.tournaments.Find(id);
  string street = tournament.Address.Street; // second query to DB happens here
  ```
- Explicit loading:

  ```cs
  Tournament tournament = context.tournaments.Find(id);
  context.Entry(tournament).Reference(t => t.Address).Load();
  // second query to DB happens here
  ```

  This is similar to lazy loading because you also need two queries and roundtrips to the database, but you control explicitly when the `Address` is loaded. Explicit loading has the option to filter or sort the related data (in case of navigation collections) which the other two options do not have.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful. I used the Eager loading method.